# Simplify a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This sequence of numbers below are not arithmetic  or geometric.  As such, i cannot understand  how to proceed when asked to 'Simplify this series'.

1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,.....

Can i write this as 1, 4, 9, 16, 25,.... ? In this way, obviously it is sequence of squares. As such, it can be simplified as below.

Sum= (n (n+1)(2n+1))/6

But if i proceed in this way, am i straying away from simplifying it?

Comment: Ah so you mean to calculate the sum of this sequence? In that case, indeed there are always 1 ones,  2 twos, 3 threes etc etc ... But be careful of the "intermediate" sum, for example the sum of the first 8 terms!

Comment: "Simplify this series" is fantastically vague. I have no idea what that's supposed to mean (although "find a closed form formula" is a first guess). Also, it's a sequence, not a series.

Comment: I think "simplify the series" means "provide a formula for the series". For example, the series $1,2,3,4,5,6,...$ is "simplified" by the formula $a_n = n$, where $a_n$ is the $n$ th term of the series. What you have to  do, is find a formula for the $n$th term of your sequence as a function of $n$. However, the use of this phrase is very ambiguous here, doubly because a series usually refers to a sum of terms.

Comment: I agree its very vague.  I will clarify what exactly the question is about.

Comment: It's still sort of unclear whether you're talking about the sequence or the sum of terms in the sequence, i.e., the associated series. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The $n^{th}$ term of the sequence is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that the associated triangular number $\sum_{r=1}^m r= \frac{1}{2}m\left(m+1\right)$ satisfies $\frac{1}{2}m\left(m+1\right) \geq n$. To find this, solve the quadratic $n = \frac{1}{2}x\left(x+1\right)$, take the positive solution (you will see that one is positive and one is negative) and then take ceiling of the result. That is, $$a_n = \lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\rceil,$$ where $\lceil\alpha\rceil$ denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $\alpha$.